# componentDidUpdate is two steps behind react-redux

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

So i have react redux application where user enters input and that input is dispatched to store and then displayed in other component. it worked perfectly when i updated the array of inputs inside reducer but now i update it inside componentDidUpdate lifecycle method and it is two steps behind the expected result, and also if i input same thing as before it does not logs. and this is the code

```
 class Equations extends React.Component{
     componentDidUpdate(nextProps){
        console.log(nextProps.equation)
        this.props.equations.unshift(nextProps.equation)
     }
     render(){
         return (
             <div>
                {this.props.equations.map((val,index)=>{
                    return (
                        <div className={index} key={index}>
                             <p>{val}</p>
                        </div>
                    )
                })}
            </div>
        )
    }
}
const mapStateToProps = state => ({
    equations: state.ER.equations,
    equation: state.ER.equation
})
export default connect(mapStateToProps, null)(Equations)
```

this is the log

[image]

last time as you see i inputted foo3 bar3 but it did not logged until i inputted foo4 bar4
in my app this is how i have components

```
class App extends React.Component{
    render(){
      return (
        <Provider store={store}>
           <div>
              <Calculator />
              <Equations />
           </div>
        </Provider>
      )
    }
}
```

Comment: You should not mutate props with unshift.

Comment: is that bad practice?

Comment: and i should not use componentDidUpdate ?

Comment: yes it is bad practice, the props come from redux store state and you're mutating it so you're mutating the store. I am scared to see your reducers now.

Comment: the componentDidupdate will be called on every dispatched action because your mapStateToProps always returns a new object reference. Not sure why you don't just provide the right structure of the props in mapStateToProps because that's what it's there for.

Comment: LOL, i have only one reducer here it is:      `export default function equateReducer(state = initialState, action){
    switch(action.type){
        case ADD_TO_EQUATIONS:
            return {
                ...state,
                //equation: action.payload.equation
                equations: [...state.equations, action.payload.equation]
            } 
         default: return state

    }
} `

I just modified code on your answer and i am updating array inside reducer.

Comment: I just started learning redux soo, i think that mistake should be forgiven

Comment: what do you mean i did not provide the right structure of the props in mapStateToProps

Comment: If you compare redux to an excel spread sheet then the cells with data is what should be in your store. Formulas should be in selectors like [reslect](https://github.com/reduxjs/reselect). The selectors are used in mapStateToProps. So if your component needs the total price of a list of orders then the selector will calculate. If your component needs `[state.ER.equation].concat(state.ER.equations)` then provide this in the mapStateToProps.